# Create Biographies

Tags: plugins, custom-field

I'm planning on doing a website where I will have a lot of biographies of different people.
Imagine I create a Page and that page will be called "Football players". Inside this page there will be a lot of biographies for different players.
For example, to create a post for Cristiano Ronaldo I would like to be like the following:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/b8Qd6.jpg

My problem is how to create the parte with the Image and his data on the left.
For the "description" and "photo gallery" I have no problems, I can just write "description" in text editor following by the text and the same for "photo gallery".
But what is the easiest way to do the top part?
Is there any way (like a plugin) with costum fields that would allow me to choose an image and fill the fields "name, nationality and birthday" and automatically put them in the top of the post like the image I posted?

Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A couple of notes here:

- You might find a custom post type to be better than using a built-in Page. You would create a post type called something like "players" or "football-players" and with it you'd have an archive. Very similar to how Posts and Categories work: you'll have one URL for each Post but also an archive like the Category that shows a bunch of the Posts together.
- Yes, you can either manually create custom fields or use a plugin. Plugin recommendations are off-topic so I suggest you do a search for WordPress custom fields plugin. Once you have those fields created, you'll need to set up theme templates - one for the archive (archive-players.php) and one for the individual players (single-players.php).

Welcome to the forum - please do some research and come back when you have more specific questions and code you've tried. :)